# If $p$ and $q$ are real number and $\lfloor np \rfloor \mid \lfloor nq \rfloor$ for all positive integers $n$ than $p$ and $q$ are integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are two distinct positive real numbers with the property that $\lfloor np \rfloor$ divides $\lfloor nq \rfloor$ for all positive integers $n$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Prove that $p$ and $q$ are integers.

My initial idea was to try writing out the form of each floor function as in, suppose $\lfloor p \rfloor=k$ which implies $k \leq p<k+1$. Now assuming, $\lfloor q \rfloor=\lfloor p \rfloor s$ we get $sk \leq q \leq sk+1$ and trying to do something like induction since the case $n=2$ is quite obvious typically avoiding equality case and getting $2k<2p<2k+2$ would imply $\lfloor 2p \rfloor=2k+1$ and so on, although I couldn't find some nice argument and secondly it turned out it is not very useful at that. Our aim is to probably consider that it lies between 2 consecutives and show some kind of contradiction forcing upon the equality thus integral case. It would be very useful if one would attach a nicely explained solution. One can request any clarification required.

P.S: My original idea might not make sense so kindly don't force yourself to try and understand it.

Comment: Hint: Write $p$ and $q$ as $p=\lfloor p\rfloor + s$ and $q=\lfloor q\rfloor + t$ where $s,t\in[0,1)$. Also, if $m$ is an integer and $x$ is any non-negative number, we have that $\lfloor m+x\rfloor = m+\lfloor x\rfloor$. What happens if $ns\geq1$ or $nt\geq 1$?

Comment: @student91 $\lfloor np \rfloor=n \lfloor p \rfloor+\lfloor ns \rfloor$ and $\lfloor nq \rfloor=n \lfloor q \rfloor+\lfloor nt \rfloor$, can u help further?

Comment: Hint: For $ s \geq 2$, what can you say about$ \lfloor nq \rfloor / \lfloor np \rfloor \approx s $?  Can it be $s-1$ or $s+1$?

Comment: You  could use an epsilon argument to show for and $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n$ so that $1 \le \frac {np}{[np]} < 1 + \epsilon; 1\le \frac {nq}{[nq]} < 1+ \epsilon$ and therefore we can conclude $p|q$.  As $p\ne q$.  If $p,q$ are not integers then we can find some "trigger" intervals where $q$ is between two fractions more tightly than $p$ is and that when you multiply them by the denominator and floor the result you get an offset.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clfloor%20np%5Crfloor%5Cmid%5Clfloor%20nq%5Crfloor%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Floor function](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1353624p7401244) which, unfortunately, currently has no answers.